# User input it iterate list and continue loop

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, if-statement, while-loop

I am writing a program in python3 to keep score of N number of players and am having trouble getting the score to be input correctly from each player. the code in bold is where I am having an issue. The loop closes after I enter the score for the first contestant and i for some reason equals 3 instead of increasing from 0 to 1. I would like 'i' to update as the loop continues so that the code to get scores continues until each player has been scored.

I don't know how to get the result I want. Am I using the wrong loop statement?

I have tried while, if and for statements.

I just started coding Tuesday so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import csv
from array import *

names = []
con = int(input("Number of Contestants: "))
maxSurfers = con #number of surfers
while len(names) < maxSurfers:
        name = input(" Enter your Name: ")
        names.append(name)
        print("Contestants")
        print(names)
else:
       print("Thank You for Participating!\n")
       print("Sign up is now closed")


**score = array('f', [])
i = 0
n = int(input("Number of Waves for "+names[i]+": "))
while i != n:
    x=float(input("Enter score for each wave: "))
    score.append(x)
    i = i + 1
print(i)
print("Winner being decided.")**

outputs:
Number of Contestants: 2
 Enter your Name: frank
Contestants
['frank']
 Enter your Name: bart
Contestants
['frank', 'bart']
Thank You for Participating!

Sign up is now closed
Number of Waves for frank: 3
Enter score for each wave: 9.6
Enter score for each wave: 7.8
Enter score for each wave: 7.2
3
Winner being decided.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have a loop for each wave but not an outer loop for each name. You also only have one score list so if you did have an outer loop you'd just have a score list with a bunch of numbers and no way to connect them to each player. You should look into python dictionaries they will likely make your life a lot easier. Also when you want a python loop for a range of numbers the standard way is with something like `for counter in range(10):` which counts from 0 to 9.

try something like:

```
scores = {}
for name in names:
    numWaves = int(input("Number of Waves for "+name+": "))
    newScores = []
    for i in range(numWaves):
        newScores.append(float(input("Enter score for each wave: ")))
    scores[name] = newScores
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! I'll try that right now. Didn't know if lists or arrays were better for what I needed. Looks like I got some more reading to do. Thanks again! I'll update you if It works.